# 'IConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddAzureAppConfiguration'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Trying to setup Azure App Configuration with Azure Key Vault in Program.cs and getting following error:

> 'IConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddAzureAppConfiguration'

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var settings = config.Build();

            config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
            {
                options.Connect(settings["ConnectionStrings:AppConfig"])
                        .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
                        {
                            kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
                        });
            });
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>());
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

adding following package fixed it:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore
```

Answer (score 7):

Or even better:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration
```

Comment: The method exists in the package you have provided, that is true, but the whole package is included in the Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore ...

Answer (score 0):

Clear and simple [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core?tabs=core5x) for the App Config integration.